# How can I configure xubuntu notifications to disappear at mouseover?

Tags: xubuntu, notification

I would like to make xubuntu notifications (xfce4-notifyd) to get dismissed after I've moved my mouse cursor on them. Is this possible / how can I do this?

Preferably, I would also like them to stick around forever until I've dismissed them with a mouseover.

And even better would be if there could be a minimum time (5s) the notification would always remain displayed, mouseover or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can edit the code, you cannot do this with the current implementation of xfce's notification daemon.